# PlayscapeManager won't initialize on android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playscape

Im not getting any errors or debug messages in adb logcat. 
But if im trying to press the Catalog(More Games) button, i get:

> I/Unity   (16917): AndroidJavaException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.execute(java.lang.Runnable)' on a
>   null object reference I/Unity   (16917):   at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in :0  I/Unity   (16917):   at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallVoidMethod (IntPtr obj, IntPtr
>   methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in :0
>   I/Unity   (16917):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._Call
>   (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in
>   :0  I/Unity   (16917):   at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.Call (System.String methodName,
>   System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0  I/Unity
>   (16917):   at Playscape.Internal.PlayscapeCatalogAndroid.showCatalog
>   () [0x00000] in :0  I/Unity   (16917):   at
>   Playscape.Catalog.Catalog.showCatalog () [0x00000] in :0  I/Unity   (16917):   at PlayscapeCatalog.ShowCatalog ()
>   [0x00000] in :0  I/Unity   (16917):
>   UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions)
>   I/Unity   (16917): UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(Strin

Anyone know what it can be? Its like the PlayscapeManager isn't initialized, 
but i have tried to put it in more scenes and it doesn't work.

I can see it works in the editor when i play it, but not on the phone.

Comment: Hi Dan, a couple of questions: a) Have you encountered any errors during the build? did the post-build process completed successfully? b) Have you implemented your own Application class? if so, does it contain an onCreate() method?

Comment: Hi Zvi, no i haven't got any errors except the own above.. It builds fine, no errors at all, and no haven't implemented any of my own application classes.. But i use Facebook, google and soomla sdks.

Comment: Have you followed the integration guide carefully and implemented all stages?

Comment: Yes, everyone of them.

Comment: Hi @Zvi, Still getting the same error with the new SDK (1.14).. Found out the PlayscapeManager is running, but when it has to call the .jar files, it put out the error above. Any ideas?

Comment: We discovered a bug in the latest SDK that we've fixed. Can you please download the fixed version (1.14.160) from the following link:
http://dashboard.playscape.com/download/PlayscapePublishingKit-unity.zip

Comment: Hi Sharon, Got most of it to work now! Thanks! But I can only make it work without the ads! If i enable the ads, i cant open the game on the device..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by updating the *SDK* and doing a new strip of the google play services *JAR*.